# Angular Material multiple "input" on same row

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How can I add multiple inputs on same row? I have tried using bootstrap but for some reason it wont work. If you have some exemple to show me.

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="First Name">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Last Name">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: Please show some HTML and CSS...

Comment: @KelvinLai it is a simple code, I have added

Comment: I smell a rat in your CSS (example-full-width)! I just tried your example in my code and I saw both on the same line. Also, you could always have these components in a table with one row and two columns.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Angular Material's inputs are displaying in row by default (see stackblitz below), and may be you override this behavior somewhere in your project, I mean CSS rules. If you like Flexbox, you can use [**@angular/flex-layout**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout), you can easily control how to display items: in row or in column, and this package is very common among Angular developers. Here is a simple demo with *"default"* behavior (without any additional rules) and 2 layout options: `column` and `row`:

[**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j748jf?file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.html)

Comment: I don't have any CSS, it's a new projet

Comment: @Rubyen Do your inputs looks like Material inputs? I mean, do they render properly (except that they are not in row)? And their default  animation works?

Comment: They look like Material inputs, I have added flex-layout to my project and tried to used it, but it wont put on the same row. I took the code from demo.

Comment: @Rubyen, tell us, what the problem was)

Comment: well it was an css, that I forgot about, it was a width that was put to 100%, but the class was put on the input

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking at the **css** style `display: block;` Change whatever you are looking at to `display: inline-block`;

**edit**

Now that you showed some code. Your basic html is fine, it shows the inputs next to each other. So something is wrong inside your example-form or example-full-width classes.

Comment: I have changed to display:inline-block but it doesn't change